# How to add a preference programmatically from normal activity in Android?

Tags: java, android, preference

I need to add a preference from an activity witch does not extend PreferenceActivity, i tried this:

```
PreferenceCategory targetCategory = (PreferenceCategory)findPreference("kurse");
                    EditTextPreference neuerKursEintrag = new EditTextPreference(SettingsActivity.this);
                    neuerKursEintrag.setKey("kurs");
                    targetCategory.addPreference(neuerKursEintrag);
```

but it does not work, because android studio cannot resolve the method `findPreference(java.lang.String)`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [at the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html#findPreference(java.lang.CharSequence)). The method signature is not `findPreference(String preferenceName)`, it's `findPreference (CharSequence key)`